# Visual Studio 2013: Cannot change icon [VB]

Tags: c#, vb.net, git, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm programming in Visual Basic using VS2013 Express for Windows Desktop.  I've chosen an application icon a while ago, but now I want to change it.  I selected the new icon and cleaned and rebuilt the solution, but still the old icon shows.

I'm using VS's Git features to work on a Git repo hosted on GitHub.  I have tried re-downloading the repo (note the repo does not even have the first icon pushed and is thus iconless), but still, when re-building the iconless exe, it still shows the first icon.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx?

Comment: Looks like they just show /how/ to add an icon.

I did the things they listed. Even with the new repo, no icon shows in the settings or folders, but still, when building, the exe has the old icon.  Maybe VS has a temp folder where it got the icon from

Comment: Yeah I think you're correct. The image has been cached by Windows. If you give the app a new name, it'll create a new reference and the icon will probably disappear. I think I found someone who had a similar issue. Check here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?701551-RESOLVED-Icon-won-t-change-on-Explorer

Comment: Thanks!

I cleared the icon cache and voila!
That is so irritating, though...

Comment: I'll add it as an answer if you don't mind and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I think you're correct. The image has been cached by Windows. If you give the app a new name, it'll create a new reference and the icon will probably disappear. I think I found someone who had a similar issue. Check here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?701551-RESOLVED-Icon-won-t-change-on-Explorer

Comment: Thanks, again!

I cleared the icon cache and that fixed it [see the last comment on the posted link]